# How to get users location bounding box from google fit api

Tags: android, android-location, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm trying to get the users step count and location bounding box in the last 24 hours from google fit API.

I don't have a problem with the step count but i'm getting an error for the location.

CODE:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // Optionally, add additional APIs and scopes if required.
                .addApi(Fitness.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
} 

private class getFitnessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.e("getFitnessTask", "getFitnessTask");
        getStepsToday();
        getLocation();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    }
}

private void getStepsToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    DataSet stepData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {

            int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();
            totalSteps += steps;

        }
    }

    Log.e("FITNES", "total steps: " + totalSteps);
}

private void getLocation() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    DataSet locationData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.AGGREGATE_LOCATION_BOUNDING_BOX);

    Log.e("FIT", locationData.toString());
    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : locationData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {

            Log.e("FITNES", field.toString());

        }
    }

}
```

i get the erorr in this:

```
DataSet locationData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.AGGREGATE_LOCATION_BOUNDING_BOX);
```

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Attempting to read data for com.google.location.bounding_box, which
>   was not requested

So What is missing? How can i get the location bounding box?
Thanks